# Unity 5.0: Sprite.Create error message "!hasError"

Tags: sprite, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I came back to a Unity game that I was working on a couple of weeks ago, using version 4.6.1. After upgrading to version 5.0 and converting the project, there was an error in the following line:

Sprite.Create(plusTexture, Rect(toRightBoundry, 0, plusTexture.width, plusTexture.height), rightPos);

The image is imported as a single Sprite , 150 pixels per unit, pivoted at the center, using a bilinear filter. The import mode is compression , with a max size of 1024. Given those conditions and the fact that this piece of code was not altered since the working version and also after confirming that all values passed are valid, the following error is found at runtime:

"!hasError"

I have researched in the forums and cannot find a solution for this, mostly topics that end in the developers asking for a bug report. Is anyone familiar with how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

it looks like an error do to unresolved merge conflicts from sprite atlas meta file of the resource file.  We were getting a few funny named errors lie"aabb is not define" "!hasError" and something WIPPE.  On of them was due to artist not resolving conflicts on a mesh meta file